# ftp option to overwrite file if different size

Tags: aix, ftp

There is a script (bsh) running in a AIX 7.1 machine. The script is to download some files via FTP from another machine. I need to stop it later because some guy need to have maintenace over the machine, even if the script is not finished.

So I would like to know, if I re-run the script later, can I configure the ftp client to skip the file if a local copy already exist and is identical to the remote one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer no.

FTP is a blunt tool.  Use [wget](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html) which does provide this functionality and can pull files from an FTP server.

An even better option is to use rsync (over ssh).